# Printing filepath settings its printer and tray as argument

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to print file for example C:/exmaple.docx but I need to specify for it printer and tray which I get from print dialog. I do not now how to set tray (paper source) as argument. Setting printer as argument works. This is my code:

```
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo info = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo();

            info.Arguments = "\"" + somePrinterName + "\"";

            info.Verb = "C:\\example.docx";
            info.FileName = "C:\\example.docx";
            info.UseShellExecute = true;
            info.CreateNoWindow = true;
            info.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;

            System.Diagnostics.Process p = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

            p.StartInfo = info;
            p.Start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there are printer tray options in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace, but for Word documents you can print from a specific tray by using the Word Interop library (`Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word`).

That'd let you do something like

```
wordDocument.PageSetup.FirstPageTray = Word.WdPaperTray.wdPrinterUpperBin;
wordDocument.PageSetup.OtherPagesTray = Word.WdPaperTray.wdPrinterLowerBin;
```

There's a more fleshed-out example [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/fb1ce2fd-4421-4678-84ec-48ee67e025ee/how-set-printer-to-duplex-when-printing-using-interopword?forum=csharpgeneral) (that developer has tray selection working, but is struggling with duplex printing).

See also:

- [MSDN Reference for WdPaperTray enum](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdpapertray%28v=office.14%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)
- [MSDN Social: Printing Options C#](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/0fb86731-b02b-42ff-9c1c-5b4890154661/printing-options-c?forum=csharpgeneral)